# Numpy.savetxt - how can I ensure that saving is complete?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to use the [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) function, however from the documentation there doesn't seem to be a way to have a flag indicating if the file has been saved returned.

Is there any other way to ensure that the document was saved before continuing?

My problem is that when I save my document, the next line opens that document and I get some problems.  I used a for loop to open the document several times and compared the results.  The first time it opened it was ok.  After that the values are incorrect and the same.

**Inside a for-loop**

```
savetxt('forest_submitfile.csv', end_matrix , delimiter=',', fmt='%s,%s,%s',
              header='EventId,RankOrder,Class', comments = '')
        print('Saving for Submit in CSV SUCCESS')
        is_file_ok = False
        while not is_file_ok:
            if os.path.isfile("forest_submitfile.csv") and os.access("forest_submitfile.csv", os.R_OK):
                break
        print('Calculate AMS Metric Score')
        AMS_metric("solutionFile.csv", "forest_submitfile.csv")
```

Comment: Can you post a small program that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: I have posted the code. My Problem is that the AMS Metric Function will give me good values for the first run. But for 2nd and n-loop useless values.

Comment: forest_submitfile.csv which gets generated is a large 350-550k row file.

Comment: I think I found the error. It has something to do with sorting. Thank you for your answers I will use them in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a couple functions from `os` to check for you.
`isfile` checks for the existence of a file.
`R_OK` checks that it is in a readable state, which implies `numpy` is done writing to it.

```
yourFile = "C:\folder\folder\file.txt"

import os
if os.path.isfile(yourFile) and os.access(yourFile, os.R_OK):
    # if you got into this check, your file is good to go!
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L887), it can raise a ValueError or an AttributeError on failure. So, maybe catch those:

```
try:
   np.savetxt('file', dataStructure)
except ValueError, e:
   print('Save failed! {}'.format(str(e))
   raise SystemError
except AttributeError, e:
   print('Save failed! {}'.format(str(e))
   raise SystemError
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: While the question is somewhat unclear it doesn't seem to indicate that there was any exception thrown - just that the data in the saved file was incorrect/broken

Comment: I interpreted it as saying that OP wanted to check if numpy had written the file correctly. So I pointed them to the function source and illustrated that there are two exceptions that could be raised.